# Saving 10,000 records Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I work with the synchronization application. How do I "roughly" open the database (Core Data) to perform 10,000 operations (delete, save, etc.) and then close?

I understand that now works like this:

- opened database
- done action
- closed and so 10,000 times.

Correct if wrong, I will be only too happy

Answer (score 1):

Just do your 10,000 operations and at the end save the managed object context. Just make sure to save at the end and not after each object. This will speed up the progress dramatically.

Comment: I find with this that there is a balance between speed and memory usage. The more you change without saving the more memory is used. The memory is then cleared when saving. So you may have trouble updating all in one go.

Comment: I have a lot of methods like this :

+ (User*) userWithLogin:(NSString*)login{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"login == %@", login];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"login" ascending:YES]];
    AGDBWorker* dbw = [AGDBWorker sharedWorker];
    User *user = (User *) [dbw fetchManagedObjectWithEntityName:entityName                            predicate:predicate
                                                sortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 
    return user;
}

and i go to this method a lot of times

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by the above message. Fogmeister is right, so I would add a conditional to save every 1,000 or so

Comment: what about...if i have 10000 records , in each of them change one property (quickly)